# Discord Python Bot embed value return function not text

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

i build a function for my discord bot which is parsing informations from a website.
in my task i want to display every 30min these data, but i want to have multiple values so i thought i could do things like this:

function a:

```
async def test99():
        link = my_link
        f = requests.get(link) 
        if "Login </td><td align=left><img src=img/on.gif" in f.text:
            return "haha"
        else:
            return "huhu"
```

my "task":

```
@tasks.loop(seconds=900)
async def called_once_a_day_cores():
        embedVar = discord.Embed(title="Status", url="XXX",  description="TESTING", color=0x00ff00)
            embedVar.add_field(name="Login", value=test99, inline=True)
            await message_channel.send(embed=embedVar)
```

output from discord bot in discord channel:

```
<function test99 at 0x000001E75751FE50>
```

Comment: You have to actually define `test99`. Making a function out of it will not work from my knowledge. Also your output tells you that something is wrong with the created embed/the way you defined it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you just need to call the function.

```py
embedVar.add_field(name="Login", value=await test99(), inline=True)
```

You should also consider that `request.get` is blocking. You should use aiohttp (included with discord.py dependencies).

```py
from aiohttp import ClientSession as CS

async def test99():
    link = my_link
    async with CS() as cs:
        async with cs.get(link) as r:
            if "Login </td><td align=left><img src=img/on.gif" in await r.text():
                return "haha"
            else:
                return "huhu"
```

Comment: ty for the detailed answer!

Comment: Well upvote :P jk, only if you feel it was a good answer and that it helped you

Comment: sorry, forgot to upvote. i just solved differently but also tried your method and it worked aswell.